# ¿Por qué no escribe en el fichero?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en Java e intentado escribir contenido en un fichero, pero el contenido no se guarda. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir esto y qué debo hacer para solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
// ...

    if(cars.exists()==true){
        System.out.println("El Fichero existe, desea continuar? (si/no)");
        if((input.nextLine())=="si"){
            pw.println("# Lista de coches");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fin del Programa");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el pw.close() cuando dejes de escribir

```
public class EscribirArchivo {
    public void escribirEnArchivo(String ruta, String nombre, String extension) {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(ruta+File.separator+nombre+extension);
            pw.write("Hola mundo");
            pw.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error-->" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!